# Running unit test in golang error: %1 is not a valid win32 application

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am trying to run the unit test cases written in go lang. While executing the test cases, i am getting error like "%1 is not a valid Win32 application".

I have already tried re-installing go, but still the problem persists.

**go.exe test dir -run ^(testname)$**

**fork/exec C:\user\username\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build976684114\packageName.test: %1 is not a valid win32 application.**

Error: Tests failed.

The above mentioned folder is not created as well. Not sure, what is happening.

Comment: I have the same error. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

if i set my GOOS to windows it is working

set GOOS=windows

Comment: There is no need to set GOOS on Windows for a normal Go installation.

Answer (score 0):

If `go env GOOS` produces a different operating system than your own, then you can restore it to its default value by unsetting the environment variable `GOOS`.

The same applies for `GOARCH` and any plattform-specific variables, such as `GOARM`.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting your PC!!!
I don't know exactly but this may cause because by temporary files clashing with your go instance

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30980746)